# Searching for a specific slider/carousel script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently writing an one-page website and I want to add a carousel/slider for my team section to slide in and out the staff. The staff is positioned in a responsive card. I want the slider to look like the one from the "partner"-section from this website: https://madeby.google.com/intl/de_de/home/ , but I can't figure out how they did it on this site and I've already searched for something similiar for ages.

Can anyone provide me a similar script or idea for me to realize it?

Thank you in advance, F9lke

Comment: Please review the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for asking questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why this is off topic and how to ask.

Comment: Slick carousel does this already. Just add the plugin to your site and adjust the auto speed to your liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) using its autoplay options.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
  });
});
```

```css
.doc-content
{
  margin: 0 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT93-yg0fIkCugU3rZubE2kJ2GU01kj5UONreRXD-_cMNa2wyIULg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.doc-content h3, p
{
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.doc-content img
{
  width: auto;
  height: 37px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="autoplay">
  <div class="doc-content">
    <h3>your content 1</h3>
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="doc-content">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVsh94BQQeuJYdImIg_di1yKk9iWEoaMZxSqbnl1pUCcr0ov1Qpw" />
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="doc-content">
    <h3>your content 3</h3>
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="doc-content">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVsh94BQQeuJYdImIg_di1yKk9iWEoaMZxSqbnl1pUCcr0ov1Qpw" />
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="doc-content">
    <h3>your content 5</h3>
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="doc-content">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVsh94BQQeuJYdImIg_di1yKk9iWEoaMZxSqbnl1pUCcr0ov1Qpw" />
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

It has an auto play option...and using css, you can make the bars at the bottom that fill up.

EDIT:
Looking at the page's source, it seems that the page with the slider actually uses slick.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Flickity: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/

It has a ton of options and events. You probably can get to the desired behaviour adjusting these options.